# Table count is more than File record count in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I'm using the SQL server exported file as the input of my hive table (having 40 columns). There are around 6 million rows in the data file, but when I load that file in the hive table, I find the record count more than row count in file. The table has 15 records more than that of the input text file.

I suspect the presence of new line characters `\n` in the data, but due to the huge volume of data I'm unable to manually check and remove these characters from the data file.

Is there any way by which I can manage my table count exactly equal to that of file count? Can I make my load query to consider those new line characters as data instead of record delimiter? or is there any other issue?

Comment: Add a data sample

Comment: I have just assumed the presence of '\n' characters. Please let me know how to handle such scenario if data contains new line charecter as the part of any field itself. Due to organisational policy I can't add any client add which is causing this issue.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to remove the newlines before / as part of the export. As StackOverflow history teaches us, for some mysterious reasons, no user was ever able to re-export the data, and I would assume this is also the case here. We can create a new fixed file but I would need to know the data structure (delimiters? qualifiers?)

Comment: The file is ` delimited. Sample record : abc`20`def`10.5 (For a four column record). Searching and replacing is not going to be an ideal solution plus this is not the case of sqoop import. This is a text file which has been loaded using 'load data local inpath.....' command.

Comment: Please add the data sample to your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sqooping input to hdfs/hive then you may use `--hive-drop-import-delims` or `--hive-delims-replacement` options of sqoop.

> Hive will have problems using Sqoop-imported data if your database’s
>   rows contain string fields that have Hive’s default row delimiters (\n
>   and \r characters) or column delimiters (\01 characters) present in
>   them.
>   You can use the **--hive-drop-import-delims** option to drop those
>   characters on import to give Hive-compatible text data.
>   Alternatively, you can use the **--hive-delims-replacement** option to replace > those characters with a user-defined string on import to give
>   Hive-compatible text data.
>   These options should only be used if you
>   use Hive’s default delimiters and should not be used if different
>   delimiters are specified.
>
> [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive)

---

Alternatively, if you are copying files onto hdfs using some other method, then just run a replace script/command over the files.

Comment: **(1)** If you are going to that direction is is worthwhile to mention `-hive-delims-replacement` as an option **(2)** You can save the readers a round-trip by quoting  the relevant part, furthermore links tends to break, especially if you are referring to a specific version of an incubating project. **(3)** A generic suggestion as "run a replace script/command" is not a solution

Comment: This is not the case of Sqoop import and next I just don't know that which character is causing this increase in row count. So, search and replace is also not going to work. This is a text file which has been loaded using 'load data local inpath.....' command.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as to run a simple unix command and clean the source data.

sed -i 's/\r//g'

After applying this command on the dataset to remove carraige returns I was able to load the hive table with expected record count.